# Proof of $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in A$ with $f$ continuous and $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in A$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $f:V\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and assume that $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in A$. I want to prove that $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in\overline{A}$ (the closure of $A$).

I thought doing this with a contradiction: Assume to the contrary that $f(x)< 0$ for a certain $x\in\overline{A}$. Then we know that for all $\delta>0 :B(x;\delta)\cap A\neq \emptyset$. So there must exist a $p\in A$ where for $f(p)\geq 0$.

We also know that $f$ is continuous, so for all $a\in V$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in V$ with $|x-a|<\delta$: $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.

So, i thought that, if i choose the right epsilon and use the things stated above, maybe i can get a contradiction using the triangle inequality. Someone have a tip / confirm my "strategy"? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x)<0$ for some $x\in\overline A$, take $\delta>0$ such that$$y\in B(x;\delta)\implies |f(y)-f(x)|<-f(x).$$Note that\begin{align}|f(y)-f(x)|<-f(x)&\implies f(y)\in\bigl(2f(x),0\bigr)\\&\implies f(y)<0.\end{align}But this is impossible, since $x\in\overline A$ and therefore $B(x;\delta)$ contains elements of $A$.

Comment: why does |f(y)-f(x)| <-f(x) tell us that f(y) is contained in (-2f(x),0)?

Comment: I meant to write that $f(y)\in(2f(x),0)$. Anyway, since$$-f(x)+f(y)\leqslant|-f(x)+f(y)|=|f(y)-f(x)|<-f(x),$$you have $f(y)<0$. And, since$$f(x)-f(y)\leqslant|f(y)-f(x)|<-f(x),$$$-f(y)<-2f(x)$, and therefore $f(y)>2f(x)$.

Comment: It's clear. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

With sequences: let $x_0 \in \bar A.$ Then there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ such that $x_n \to x_0.$ Since $f$ is continuous, we get $f(x_n) \to f(x_0).$ From $f(x_n) \ge 0$ for all $n$, we then derive that $f(x_0) \ge 0.$